# Get description from ExceptionCode

Tags: winapi, seh

Is there an API for translating ExceptionCode:s in an ExceptionRecord to a readable message like FormatMessage for regular errors.

Comment: Yes, FormatMessage().  Exception codes are however typically native operating system error codes, not winapi error codes.  So you'll need the FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE and pass the module handle you get from GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll").  The required FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS option is however troublesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in function for this.

Many people are doing it manually:

`fostlib::exceptions::structured::structured` in:
http://svn.felspar.com/public/fost-base/tags/4.12.12.44490/fost-base/Cpp/fost-core/exception-win.cpp

`MyUnHandledExceptionFilter` in:
http://openholdembot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ManualMode/debug.cpp

`GetExceptionString` in:
http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/ub-source113/Standard%20Gaming%20Platform/ExceptionHandling.cpp

Comment: Or some code generation

#!/bin/sh
echo "const size_t N_MESSAGES=$(grep 'STATUS_' 'D:\bin-win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winnt.h'|wc -l);">> seh.stub
echo "ExceptionName exceptions[]=" >>seh.stub
echo " {" >>seh.stub
grep "STATUS_" "D:\bin-win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winnt.h"\
|sed 's/#define \(.*\) ((DWORD)\(.*\))/\t{\2,STR("\1")},/g'|sort >> seh.stub
echo " };" >>seh.stub